# Add Text beyond all Stack column charts in wpf

Tags: wpf, charts

I want to draw a report with Stack Column Chart in Wpf,
I can add text inside each chart to represent the value,
here is my code to do so :

```
<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
     <Rectangle>
          <Rectangle.Fill>
               <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1"/>
               </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Rectangle.Fill>
     </Rectangle>
     <Border BorderBrush="#ccffffff" BorderThickness="1">
          <Border BorderBrush="#77ffffff" BorderThickness="1"/>
     </Border>
     <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0"/>
     <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
     <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2"/>
</Grid>
```

and the result is like 
[image]

and this is what I want to achieve : 
[image]

the black text shown at the top is the sum of the values of each chart.
Is there any method could do this? Thanks!

Comment: Best would be to create a viewmodel, and then lay everything inside a stackpanel as everything in your bar in vertically stacked. Your model would contain blue-value, red-value and their sum.

Comment: Thanks! I get it, but I still want to know is there any existing and useful methods could achieve this?

Comment: don't think so. may be some custom chart control provider providing some api for this.

Comment: OK! I will take your advice and try to do that. Really appreciate!